# How to zoom_in 3D plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have a dataset I display it in 3D. now I have to look deep into that 3D plot. because there is a hole in it and I have to find it. Now I don't know how to do it. The 3D I display.
[image: The 3D I display]

and I want to extract this from the above image
[image: zoom to see this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3D viewing distance/angles, there are 3 parameters that you need to specify appropriately:

```
ax3d.azim = 150   # z rotation (default=270)
ax3d.elev = 42    # x rotation (default=0)
ax3d.dist = 10    # define perspective (default=10)
```

If you want to zoom-in, `ax3d.dist` should be set smaller than the default value.

However, the plot limits are also important in such situations. These lines of code are also needed:

```
ax3d.set_xlim3d(low_x, high_x)
ax3d.set_ylim3d(low_y, high_y)
ax3d.set_zlim3d(low_z, high_z)
```