# How to display a 3d image of .stl file

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, stl-format

I've got a task of reading a stl image and need to display in my python environment. To do that, I have written the code below, but it is not working. When I tried with `plt.imshow` instead of `plt.show()`, it shows only vertical column with shape (92520, 3, 3). Is it possible to view the full 3D image I have or not?

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from stl import mesh

# Load the STL mesh
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('/content/stlimage.stl')

# Create a new figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = mplot3d.Axes3D(fig)

# Add the mesh to the plot
ax.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(your_mesh.vectors))

# Set plot labels
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please explain how the tag [tag:STL], a C++ library is related to Python, the file extension or 3d images?

Comment: @273K because the OP didn't read the tag description.

Comment: It's not reproducible without the file. Also does it need to be scaled? [How to plot a .stl file with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74617585/7758804) and [How to zoom_in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65016029/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `open3d` package to 3D visualize a `.stl` file. Here's how you can do it:

- Installation

```
pip install open3d
```

- Usage

```
import open3d as o3d

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("DeathStarTop_Hollow.stl")
mesh = mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh], window_name="STL", left=1000, top=200, width=800, height=650)
```

Output:
[image]

You will see an interactable 3D stl file.

Check out [**`open3d` documentation**](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/introduction.html) to know more.

Comment: thanks for your response..but i am not able to see the image in window..its just showing a white screen..

Comment: Do you see any error/warning messages in the output? If not check your stl file, if that actually contains anything. One way to do that is, `print(mesh)` to see if it contains anything

Comment: yes you are correct but i am able to upload the image in blender and also i am able to upload the image in 3D slicer which is a platform for viewing medical images.

Comment: can you share your `.stl` file?

Comment: Now its working , earlier i didn't save the python file so its not showing the output.Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: hello now i want to see the 3d image in coordinate axes..how to add the axis to the mesh we have?